# How to Have Drupal WebForm phone number input show a keypad on a mobile device

Tags: mobile, drupal, drupal-webform

I'm working with webforms in Drupal and looking for a way to customize how the fields are handled on a mobile device. One in particular is the phone number field. I'm looking to have the number keyBoard show up rather than the qwerty one when the field is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number keyboard is triggered by using HTML 5 form elements:

`<input type="number" />
<input type="tel" />`

These are not part of drupal 7 core webform, so have a look at the [Elements](https://www.drupal.org/project/elements) module to enable it.

Comment: Adding the elements module helped a great deal. We ended up writing hooks to the implement the values. Here's the code:

Comment: There must be something wrong, I don't see the code. Glad I could help, if the answer was to your liking, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the [Telephone module](https://www.drupal.org/project/telephone). It is a backport of the Drupal 8 core 'telephone' module, which means it has been rigorously tested (and if you ever upgrade to D8, will provide a seamless integration--one less headache!). It works with the Elements module linked by DenialofService.